# Is my hard drive failing or is it the issue with netbeans?

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, netbeans

I am having this issue for the last 7-8 months but now it has crossed all limits. The issue is like this:
I am coding in netbeans 8.x. Suddenly all project files will become read only and netbeans will start dsiplaying 5-6 messages like .config is read only( I dont remember the exact messages). Now the worst part will happen. My whole filesystem will become readonly. Now I must reboot. On rebooting I will be presented with initramfs: and asked to do fsck. I will do fsck and then ubuntu will start and everything will become normal. Then again someday this thing will happen.

Then finally one day after fsck ubuntu started showing message like READ FPDMA QUEUED, DRY error and ubuntu failed to start.

I installed a fresh ubuntu and then everything was working fine. Then I installed netbeans and then again the same thing happened. So here I was again doing fsck and then the same message READ FPDMA QUEUED. Finally installed ubuntu again and then posting this question.

I have searched a lot for the messages shown and suggestion was to check my hard disk health. First I used the disks utility in ubuntu. So overall assessment was Ok(48 sectors as bad). But then I did smart test. The test failed.

Then I used smartctl. Overall assessment OK.

Now I am confused if the problem is due to netbeans or my hard disk is failing. My laptop is around 5 years old and apart from running netbeans I have never encountered this problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this ONLY happens when using NetBeans, then it's obviously NetBeans or a plugin for it that is giving you grief.  The only way to know is to test it by using something else.

Comment: You're getting NCQ disk errors. Before I put together an answer for you, first, edit your question and show me screenshots of the `Disks` application **SMART Data** window (it's scrollable, so it may take 2 screenshots). Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have added the screenshots.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema For now I have stopped using netbeans 8 and have installed apache netbeans 12. Have not used netbeans 12 yet. And have not faced any issue till now. When I start coding again and if the issue arises then I will try your solution and then update.

Comment: Don't be fooled. This is not a netbeans problem. You still have a hardware problem.

Comment: @heynnema I am backing up my important data everyday.

Comment: You might just as well do my answer now, as you'll have to some time anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting NCQ (Native Command Queuing) disk errors, combined with bad blocks on the disk.

**fsck**

Let's first check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**NCQ**

**Note**: You may be able to undo this after the bad blocking is complete.

Native Command Queuing (NCQ) is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

Edit `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and change the following line to include this extra parameter. Then do `sudo update-grub` to write the changes to disk. Reboot. Monitor hangs, and watch `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` for continued error messages.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

**Bad Blocking**

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got 48 bad sectors. It's a lot of bad sectors. Use the drive only for non-important data.

If the drive has 1 or 2 bad sectors, it is not a problem, but if it has more, I would personally replace it to worry less about it.

Keep an eye on it. If the number of bad sectors increases in a short time replace it. If you can't get it replaced, keep it for non-important data. In any case, you should back up your data now.

If under warranty then give it in they will replace the drive for you.

Hope this helps anyone! :)

- Read more about bad sectors here: [Bad Sectors Explained: Why Hard Drives Get Bad Sectors and What You Can Do About It](https://www.howtogeek.com/173463/bad-sectors-explained-why-hard-drives-get-bad-sectors-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/)

Comment: It's not a Netbeans issue. It's more of an HDD issue.